# SQL Server : join with top record selection

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

```
Clientcode  Emailaddress    Accountcode clientname      phoneno
----------------------------------------------------------------
AAA         ragu@bib.com        100     Berjeya         90909090
AAA         ragu1@bib.com       100     Berjeya         90909090
AAABBB      jkkjkj@bib.com      200     Berjeya sooo    3222
CCCC        dfdf@bib.com        200     Berjeya klkl    123
dddd        sdsdsd@bib.com    33300     Berjeya penn    33333
```

This is the data in my table, I need to remove any one of the email address with same client code and account code. For example the email address `ragu@bib.com` and `ragu1@bib.com` have the same client code and account code, but email address is different; I need to show only one of the email addresses with all records. Please suggest the suitable query for this.

Comment: Looks like this is SQL Server question... Do tag that to SQL Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use top 1 with ties as below:

```
Select top (1) with ties * from yourtable
   order by row_number() over(partition by ClientCode,AccountCode order by EmailAddress)
```

with subquery you can do like below

```
Select * from (
    Select *, RowN = Row_Number() over(partition by ClientCode, AccountCode order by EmailAddress) from yourtable
 ) a where a.RowN = 1
```

Comment: I like this, it is a clever little trick to remove the need for a subquery, however, from [the testing I have just done](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=9befc63c4ebcf17ce367c357bd48c776) it appears to be too clever for the optimiser. It causes an extra sort and consistently performs worse than using a subquery with an outer predicate on the `row_number()` calculation.

Comment: Gareth the above one is very good trick.. but may i know how we can do this using sub query can you give me some sample query for above records?

Comment: @garethd you are correct one extra sort operator happens... that gives an edge for subquery approach